# Find how many people the person with the most units per alcohol per week lives with

Tags: excel, function, indexing, excel-formula, max

I have the following data collected:

[image]

hhsize: household size

drating: totals units of alcohol per week

I am trying to find a function that tells me how many people live in the house where the individual who drinks the most units of alcohol per week lives.

I know how to find the individual that drinks the most:

```
=MAX(data!Q11:Q9291)
```

But not how to link the result to the hhsize.
EDIT: The answer must be formula or function based, i.e not generated solely by sorting or filtering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could edit the below to match your needs:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=@SORT(A2:B9,2,-1)
```

Note that the 2nd parameter holds the index of the column you wish to sort by. In my case '2', in yours it's probably '14'.

Comment: What should I do if I needed to present the first value if more than one individual shared the same value? is it enough writing the @?

Comment: Would the answer by @ike not do what you describe using `FILTER()`? Or am I misunderstanding what you are asking here?

Comment: Or @andrea65, if you mean you still want the **1st** value of the first person that drinks the max, then yes the above should do so just fine.

Comment: @andrea65 the difference is that @JvdV solution asumes only a single row has the maximum value, whereas @Ike solution in case you have more than one row it returns all `hhsize` values with the max `drating` and `SORT` solution will return the first one under this scenario. The beauty of this answer from JvdV is that is very concise, but under this assumption. Then it will depend on which scenario you have in your data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but I need a method that is different from filtering, as it need to be formula or function based according to my professor (see post edit). This means that function isn't valid right?

Answer (score 4):

If you have Excel 365 than you can use this function:

```
=FILTER(data!A11:Q9291,data!Q11:Q9291 = MAX(data!Q11:Q9291))
```

Or to just return the two columns:

```
=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(data!A11:Q9291,data!Q2:Q9291 =MAX(data!Q11:Q9291 )),1,17)
```

--- UPDATE ----

If you only want the first result:

```
=TAKE(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(data!A11:Q9291,data!Q2:Q9291 =MAX(data!Q11:Q9291 )),1,17),1)
```

Comment: I have to use Excel Excel 2021. That function is compatible right?

Comment: I am not sure ...

Comment: The first formula given by @Ike madam supports `Excel 2019/Excel 2021/MS365` rest only supports `MS365` so you can use the first one as well @andrea65

Comment: It returns me the SPILL error :(

Comment: Could it be that ther is another value below? Check [here](https://exceljet.net/formulas/how-to-fix-the-spill-error) for other reasons. But the good news: Excel 2021 supports the `FILTER`-formula - otherwise you would get another error.

Comment: There are no values below, and it still displays the error...